# Python MySQLdb cursor.lastrowid

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm having problems returning auto-incremented ID columns from a MySQL database using MySQLdb python library. 
I have something like:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (\"%s\")""" %(tbl, colsf, valsf)
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    id = cursor.lastrowid
    db.close()
except:
    print "Failed to add to MySQL database: \n%s" %sql
    print sys.exc_info()
    db.close()
    exit()
```

However the lastrowid command seems to be returning incorrect values. For instance, I've tried printing out various id columns from the MySQL command line which shows them to be empty, but the lastrowid value keeps increasing by 1 every time the python script is run. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Turned out that the values weren't being committed to the MySQL database properly, adding "db.commit()" command seems to solve the problem.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (\"%s\")""" %(tbl, colsf, valsf)
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    id = cursor.lastrowid
    cursor.close()
    db.commit() 
    db.close()
except:
    print "Failed to add to MySQL database: \n%s" %sql
    print sys.exc_info()
    db.close()
    exit()
```